# Bluetooth Connection : Evolute Impress Printer not printing data

Tags: sockets, printing, android-bluetooth, thermal-printer, android-print-framework

I have an issue of connecting bluetooth device through mobile and i can able to send bytes as Outputstream but i cant able to retrive print from Evolute impress printer.Please help me how to get the print

**Problem:**

```
 how to check evolute printer whether its reciving data which i sent.
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Activity implements Runnable {
            protected static final String TAG = "TAG";
            private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE = 1;
            private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;
            Button mScan, mPrint, mDisc,check;
            BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
            private UUID applicationUUID = UUID
                    .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
            private ProgressDialog mBluetoothConnectProgressDialog;
            private BluetoothSocket mBluetoothSocket;
            BluetoothDevice mBluetoothDevice;

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle mSavedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(mSavedInstanceState);
                requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                mScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Scan);
                check = (Button)findViewById(R.id.check);



                mScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View mView) {
                        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Message1", 2000).show();
                        } else {
                            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(
                                        BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent,
                                        REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                            } else {
                                ListPairedDevices();
                                Intent connectIntent = new Intent(Main.this,
                                        DeviceListActivity.class);
                                startActivityForResult(connectIntent,
                                        REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                mPrint = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mPrint);
                mPrint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View mView) {
                        Thread t = new Thread() {
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    OutputStream os = mBluetoothSocket
                                            .getOutputStream();
                                    String BILL = "";

                                    BILL = "\nInvoice No: ABCDEF28060000005" + "    "
                                            + "04-08-2011\n";
                                    BILL = BILL
                                            + "-----------------------------------------";
                                    BILL = BILL + "\n\n";
                                    BILL = BILL + "Total Qty:" + "      " + "2.0\n";
                                    BILL = BILL + "Total Value:" + "     "
                                            + "17625.0\n";
                                    BILL = BILL
                                            + "-----------------------------------------\n";
                                    os.write(BILL.getBytes());
                                        //This is printer specific code you can comment ==== > Start

                                    // Setting height
                                    int gs = 29;
                                    os.write(intToByteArray(gs));
                                    int h = 104;
                                    os.write(intToByteArray(h));
                                    int n = 162;
                                    os.write(intToByteArray(n));

                                    // Setting Width
                                    int gs_width = 29;
                                    os.write(intToByteArray(gs_width));
                                    int w = 119;
                                    os.write(intToByteArray(w));
                                    int n_width = 2;
                                    os.write(intToByteArray(n_width));

                                    // Print BarCode
                                    int gs1 = 29;
                                    os.write(intToByteArray(gs1));
                                    int k = 107;
                                    os.write(intToByteArray(k));
                                    int m = 73;
                                    os.write(intToByteArray(m));

                                    String barCodeVal = "ASDFC028060000005";// "HELLO12345678912345012";
                                    System.out.println("Barcode Length : "
                                            + barCodeVal.length());
                                    int n1 = barCodeVal.length();
                                    os.write(intToByteArray(n1));

                                    for (int i = 0; i < barCodeVal.length(); i++) {
                                        os.write((barCodeVal.charAt(i) + "").getBytes());
                                    }
       //printer specific code you can comment ==== > End
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    Log.e("Main", "Exe ", e);
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        t.start();
                    }
                });

                mDisc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dis);
                mDisc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View mView) {
                        if (mBluetoothAdapter != null)
                            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
                    }
                });

            }// onCreate

            @Override
            protected void onDestroy() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDestroy();
                try {
                    if (mBluetoothSocket != null)
                        mBluetoothSocket.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Tag", "Exe ", e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
                try {
                    if (mBluetoothSocket != null)
                        mBluetoothSocket.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Tag", "Exe ", e);
                }
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
                finish();
            }

            public void onActivityResult(int mRequestCode, int mResultCode,
                    Intent mDataIntent) {
                super.onActivityResult(mRequestCode, mResultCode, mDataIntent);

                switch (mRequestCode) {
                case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:
                    if (mResultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        Bundle mExtra = mDataIntent.getExtras();
                        String mDeviceAddress = mExtra.getString("DeviceAddress");
                        Log.v(TAG, "Coming incoming address " + mDeviceAddress);
                        mBluetoothDevice = mBluetoothAdapter
                                .getRemoteDevice(mDeviceAddress);
                        mBluetoothConnectProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,
                                "Connecting...", mBluetoothDevice.getName() + " : "
                                        + mBluetoothDevice.getAddress(), true, false);
                        Thread mBlutoothConnectThread = new Thread(this);
                        mBlutoothConnectThread.start();
                        // pairToDevice(mBluetoothDevice); This method is replaced by
                        // progress dialog with thread
                    }
                    break;

                case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
                    if (mResultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        ListPairedDevices();
                        Intent connectIntent = new Intent(Main.this,
                                DeviceListActivity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(connectIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Message", 2000).show();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

            private void ListPairedDevices() {
                Set<BluetoothDevice> mPairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter
                        .getBondedDevices();
                if (mPairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                    for (BluetoothDevice mDevice : mPairedDevices) {
                        Log.v(TAG, "PairedDevices: " + mDevice.getName() + "  "
                                + mDevice.getAddress());
                    }
                }
            }

            public void run() {
                try {
                    mBluetoothSocket = mBluetoothDevice
                            .createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(applicationUUID);
                    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                    mBluetoothSocket.connect();
                    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                } catch (IOException eConnectException) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "CouldNotConnectToSocket", eConnectException);
                    closeSocket(mBluetoothSocket);
                    return;
                }
            }

            private void closeSocket(BluetoothSocket nOpenSocket) {
                try {
                    nOpenSocket.close();
                    Log.d(TAG, "SocketClosed");
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "CouldNotCloseSocket");
                }
            }

            private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    mBluetoothConnectProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(Main.this, "DeviceConnected", 5000).show();
                }
            };

            public static byte intToByteArray(int value) {
                byte[] b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(value).array();

                for (int k = 0; k < b.length; k++) {
                    System.out.println("Selva  [" + k + "] = " + "0x"
                            + UnicodeFormatter.byteToHex(b[k]));
                }

                return b[3];
            }

            public byte[] sel(int val) {
                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
                buffer.putInt(val);
                buffer.flip();
                return buffer.array();
            }
```

**DeviceListActivity**

```
 public class DeviceListActivity extends Activity 
    { 
    protected static final String TAG = "TAG"; 
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter; 
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter; 

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle mSavedInstanceState) 
    { 
        super.onCreate(mSavedInstanceState); 
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS); 
        setContentView(R.layout.device_list); 

        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED); 
        mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.device_name); 

        ListView mPairedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.paired_devices); 
        mPairedListView.setAdapter(mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter); 
        mPairedListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener); 

        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); 
        Set<BluetoothDevice> mPairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices(); 

        if (mPairedDevices.size() > 0) 
        { 
            findViewById(R.id.title_paired_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
            for (BluetoothDevice mDevice : mPairedDevices) 
            { 
                mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(mDevice.getName() + "\n" + mDevice.getAddress()); 
            } 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            String mNoDevices = "None Paired";//getResources().getText(R.string.none_paired).toString(); 
            mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(mNoDevices); 
        } 
    } 

    @Override 
    protected void onDestroy() 
    { 
        super.onDestroy(); 
        if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) 
        { 
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery(); 
        } 
    } 

    private OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() 
    { 
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> mAdapterView, View mView, int mPosition, long mLong) 
        { 
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery(); 
            String mDeviceInfo = ((TextView) mView).getText().toString(); 
            String mDeviceAddress = mDeviceInfo.substring(mDeviceInfo.length() - 17); 
            Log.v(TAG, "Device_Address " + mDeviceAddress); 

            Bundle mBundle = new Bundle(); 
            mBundle.putString("DeviceAddress", mDeviceAddress); 
            Intent mBackIntent = new Intent(); 
            mBackIntent.putExtras(mBundle); 
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, mBackIntent); 
            finish(); 
        } 
    }; 

 } 

        }
```

**UnicodeFormatter:**

```
public class UnicodeFormatter {

    static public String byteToHex(byte b) {
            // Returns hex String representation of byte b
            char hexDigit[] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
                    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };
            char[] array = { hexDigit[(b >> 4) & 0x0f], hexDigit[b & 0x0f] };
            return new String(array);
    }

    static public String charToHex(char c) {
            // Returns hex String representation of char c
            byte hi = (byte) (c >>> 8);
            byte lo = (byte) (c & 0xff);
            return byteToHex(hi) + byteToHex(lo);
    }

}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.printapplication"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
      <permission
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
        android:label="BLUETOOTH" >
    </permission>
    <permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" >
    </permission>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DeviceListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Which printer you are using ??

Comment: @NareshSharma:evolute Impress printer

Comment: @NareshSharma: I can able to pass bytes to OutputStream but printer is not printing.

Comment: @Giridharan, did you find any solution?

Comment: Did any of you find the  solution?